# jquery selector for elements within 'this'

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the paragraph element within a selected element to apply certain css styles. I have tried putting quotations around the p in the selector, but that did not work.

```
$('#characterSelect div').on('click',function(){
  if( !$.trim( $('#attacker').html() ).length )
  {
    $('#attacker').append(this);
    $(this p).css('margin-top','80px');
    $(this p).css('margin-right','20px');
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `find()` and since you're styling the same element, use the following syntax :

```
$(this).find('p').css({
    'margin-top':'80px',
    'margin-right':'20px'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#characterSelect div').on('click',function(){
  if( !$.trim( $('#attacker').html() ).length )
  {
    $('#attacker').append(this);
    $(this).find('p').css('margin-top','80px');
    $(this).find('p').css('margin-right','20px');
  }
 });
```